# Can lint UnusedResources check to avoid adding resource referenced by library project

Tags: android, lint

I use the command `lint --check UnusedResources project` to check the unused resource,
but  the result has some resources which is referenced by the library project.

So how can i avoid lint to add these resource to the unused resource result.

For example:

Library project B has an resource named `titile_bar.png`, which in the project A UI, i will use another title bar ui, so i put the new title_bar.png in the project A to override the title_bar.png of under library project B. So actually title_bar.png is useful to my project A. but lint check will consider it as the unused resource.

Answer (score 0):

If in case project B is another Android project in your workspace, you can open the properties of the project and go to Android Lint Preferences -> Ignore all. You could set this for the entire workspace as well (if you want).